# Замена текста в List<> c#

Tags: c#

Не знаю как правильно это реализовать.
У меня есть List<>

```
public List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Его я предварительно заполняю строкой:

```
string[] doingsometh = { Name + " - " + 
                         Convert.ToString(DenRojd) + " - " 
                       + Convert.ToString(Vozrast)};
```

Я добавляю несколько строк, как именно этому имени поменять возраст?

Comment: обратиться к элементу по индексу листа?

Comment: Т.е через IndexOf найти строку, и в ней уже менять?

Comment: 1. Всю эту ерунду, что написали, можно написать в сотню раз проще `$"{Name} - {DenRojd} - {Vozrast}"`. 2. Не коверкайте названия, не смешивайте рус. и англ. языки, это очень противно смотрится, если учитесь, то и привыкайте сразу писать правильно `DenRojd` -> `Birthday`,  `Vozrast` -> `Age`. 3. Если у вас объект из разных значений, то почему вы делаете строку? Берете класс, в нем свойства/поля, далее `List<созданный_класс>`, ну и заполняете. Вот сейчас как я понял вы хотите изменить возраст, ок, будете строку разбивать, доставая из нее нужное? Ну... Бредовое занятие, лишняя морока.

Comment: У меня созданы поля. но когда я добавляю значения, они идут списком, а не таблицей. Может есть и проще метод, я нашел простым использовать AddRange.

Comment: Непонятно примерно ничего. Список ок, но какое отношение следующий массив к нему имеет, я не могу угадать. Какую задачу решаете? Ваш вопрос - обрывок какой-то задачи и ответ на него сильно от этой общей задачи зависит. Используете какие-то перпменные, ни типов, не назначения не указали. Буквы бесплатные, оформите вопрос более полноценно. Пока ощущение, что вам вообще не нужен этот список, и есть другой выход. Что имеется? Что хотите получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хранить не строки, а объекты. Примерно так:

```
class MyClass {
   public string Name {set;get;}
   public DateTime BirthDay {set;get;}
   // зачем нужен возраст отдельно, если есть день рождения, этого я не понял
   public int Age {set;get;}
}
```

А далее делаете лист с этим классом

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
// создаем экземпляр класса и добавляем в список
var somePerson = new MyClass() {
   Name = "имя",
   BirthDay = вашаДата,
   Age = вашВозраст
}
list.Add(somePerson);
```

И немного магии Linq, чтобы проще обращаться к элементам списка:

```
// поиск по имени
var person = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "НужноеИмя");
// меняем возраст на нужный
person?.Age = 123;
```

Comment: `person.Age =` может выдать `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Да, но я думаю, что автора не стоит перегружать информацией. Захочет - спросит.

Comment: Ну просто выглядит небоежно. Если предполагается, что такой элемент строго один, то нужно использовать Single, а не First. И если используете ...OrDefault, то предполагается, что вы будете потом проверять на null, иначе нужно не использовать OrDefault, а ловить исключение сразу

Comment: Я что-то не могу понять, как вашим методом заполнить лист, через list.Add(Name) или как-то еще?

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @Snegan я дополнил ответ. В C# вам никуда без основ ООП, очень рекомендую почитать о классах и свойствах.

Comment: А как теперь вывести все данные из list? Я использовал - Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));

Comment: Все, спасибо. сделал через for - Console.WriteLine(list[i].Name + " | " + list[i].BirthDay + " | " + list[i].Age );

Comment: Обычно используют list.ElementAt или foreach